# VS Code 1.78's Source Control Repositories context menu item "Open In Terminal" is not working. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code on Ubuntu. When I right click on a git repo in the "Source Control Repositories" and select "Open In Terminal" it doesn't open a terminal. This is a recent change, as it was working just a few days ago.

The Ctrl-Shift-P commands "Terminal: Create New Terminal" works fine, as does the menu "View -> Terminal", although "Open New External Terminal" is not working consistently either.

I assume there is some secret log file that has the error message in it, but I can't find it. I've looked at every console in "View->Output" and looked for .log files under ~/.vscode. Anyone know where errors about starting new terminals is hidden?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in the command palette) into your question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug tracked in the following issue tickets:

- [Open in terminal uses windows cmd instead of VSCode integrated terminal #182602](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182602). A fix for this one has been made in [PR #183118](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/183118), and is currently marked as going in [the May 2023 release milestone](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/225). If you cant wait, there's a hotfix described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182602#issuecomment-1556868859), to edit part of your installation's `...\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\workbench.desktop.main.js` to replace a call to `openInTerminal` with `openInIntegratedTerminal`. Note that VS Code might issue a security-related warning when you tamper with the installation's files (by-design).
- [Integrated Terminal suddenly will not load from right click on source control, loads external cmd.exe instead #182076](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182076). This one is closed as a duplicate of the above, so I assume the underlying issue is the same.

For your reference / learning purposes, those issue tickets were found by googling "`github vscode issues 1.78 repo "open in terminal"`".